# How to read error from HTTP response body

Tags: json, api, go, controller, beego

This is how error looks like, I just need `"Body"` when I try `fmt.Println(err)`

**Console**

```
Expected HTTP response code [200] when accessing [POST http://controller:8774/v2.1/os-keypairs], but got 409 instead
{"conflictingRequest": {"message": "Key pair 'Darkhaa test hi' already exists.", "code": 409}}
```

**Controller**

```
createKeyPair, err := compute.CreateKeypair(raw["keyPairName"].(string))

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    lists["retType"] = -1
    lists["retDesc"] = err
} else {
    lists["retType"] = 0
    lists["retDesc"] = ""
    lists["retData"] = createKeyPair
}

i.Data["json"] = lists
```

Answer (score 1):

```
type ErrorStruct struct {
    ConflictingRequest struct {
        Message string `json:"message"`
        Code    int    `json:"code"`
    } `json:"conflictingRequest"`
}

go func() {
    _, err := compute.CreateKeypair(raw["keyPairName"].(string))
    if err != nil {
        re := regexp.MustCompile("\\{(.*?)\\}")
        match := re.FindStringSubmatch(err.Error())
        data := ErrorStruct{}
        json.Unmarshal([]byte(match[1]), data)
        log.Printf("Message: %s", data.Message)
    }
}
```

Comment: `cannot use err (type error) as type string in argument to re.FindStringSubmatch`

Comment: `data.Message undefined (type ErrorStruct has no field or method Message)`

Comment: use `err.Error()`

Comment: `type error interface {
    Error() string
}` you can get string out of error by following error intrface

Comment: i edited code `re.FindStringSubmatch(err.Error())
  `

Comment: `data.Message undefined (type ErrorStruct has no field or method Message)`